# Generate more properties when another property's count increases

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

Basically, I have a view that can have an unlimited amount of UIViews inside of it. I want to be able to set `self.numberOfSections = 8` or `self.numberOfSections = 2` and then have that same number of `UIImages` generated respectively that can then be manipulated.

Currently I have many `IBInspectible` images in my code that appear no matter if I have 2 numberOfSections or 100 numberOfSections. I would like to somehow be able to create `UIImages` based off of my numberOfSections number.

[image: rotaryWheelView]

[image: storyBoardInspect]

If I set Number Of Sections to 2 here - I can set the images in the story board, but all the other IBInspectable elements appear too that won't be used because there are only 2 sections. Is there a way to only have the ones that are needed appear? I want to set images in the storyboard. Is there a way to refactor this down so as not to have so many IBInspectables?

This is how I set the images to the various programmatically generated views in code.

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect

    for (int i = 0; i < self.numberOfSections; i++) {
       NSString *rotaryName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"rotaryImage%d", i + 1];
       id rotaryNameValue = [self valueForKey:rotaryName];
       [self.sectorView setValue:rotaryNameValue forKey:@"image"];
    }
}
```

Comment: you cant generate properties once the compiler start compiling the program. They have to be set before you run the program.

Comment: any way to add an IBInspectable to a property later in the view.m file? So it already exists @property (nonatomic) UIImage *rotaryImage1 and then later I can add IBInspectable to it.

Comment: array, ibouletcollection, data source. But definitely not generating properties.

Answer (score 5):

First of all I would say that there is a flaw in your design pattern.  If you have that many `IBInspectable UIImageView` instances, you probably should be using an `IBOutletCollection`.

Secondly, what your asking is not possible.  Why not create a single `IBInspectable` value type to set the number of sections from the storyboard, and generate your `UIImageView` objects programmatically from that number?

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable int *sections;
```

[image: Interface Builder]

Comment: Okay yeah I was unaware of IBOutletCollection existing. I want to be able to set the images in the storyboard but basically it always shows all the IBInspectables despite only having 2 numberOfSections.

Comment: @HannahLouisaCarney I'm not sure what you're asking.  You want an `IBInspectable int` that will change the number of views generated for you in Interface Builder?  That is not possible, you will need to add your views programmatically.

Comment: I suppose I want only two IBInspectable RotaryImages to appear in the storyboard to set, if you have numberOfSections set to 2, and 8 to appear if you have set it to 8. Since you can have unlimited images, but I can only type limited IBDesignables in my code.